# Run external file Java

Tags: java, file, external

How can I run an external file in Java?
Like opening a batch or a PDF file?

I want to add it to a jButton with Netbeans, so if somebody pushs on it, it will launch this file from a specified directory

Theres not a lot about this to find on the internet (except a web application, but it needs to be a file/batch/.exe ....

AS SAID its for Netbeans! Everytime I use those commands inside a Button Class:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

            // TODO add your handling code here:
            
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process pr = rt.exec("msg * hello");
        
        
    }
```

I get an error for the line:

```
Process pr = rt.exec("msg * hello");
```

Which says:

> unreported exception IOException; must be caught or declared to be
> thrown

Now how do I launch an external file?

Answer (score 2):

The [Runtime](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html) class can be used to do this. You can get an instance of this class via the static method [Runtime.getRuntime()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#getRuntime--). In the Runtime class are several `exec()` methods that should be what you need.

Finally, you may consider the [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) class more convenient depending on how complex your needs are.

Comment: look at my first post, i still have several issues